# Passing objects primary key from its view to its ManyToMany-relationship object view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I don't know if the title is clear. It's quite difficult for me to explain it in simple way because the problem is not that simple and I'm not a very good English speaker. Every suggestion for improving a title are welcome.

So, let's go to the actual problem... In my application people can join different groups. Currently, I'm creating invitation system for this purpose, so user can send an invitation to another user. In a group view, I have a list of users which are not connected with this group, which allowing group members to invite those people. So, when I'm going to the group view, I am passing it's Primary Key. To create database cell about the invitation I need a group's PK and users PK as well (I want to do it using another view, but I'm not sure it's the best solution).

My question is: **How can I pass those two PKs to the new view where I will create group-user relation cell in a database?**

**models.py**:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="member")
    invitations = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="invitations")
```

**views.py**:

```
def not_yet_members_list_view(request, pk):
    group = Group.objects.get(pk=pk)

    not_yet_members = User.objects.all() #doesn't matter

    args = {'group': group, 'not_yet_members': not_yet_members}
    return render(request, 'groups/show_members.html', args)

# Here is my problem (this code is a simplified version of what I want to achieve)
def invite_user_view(request, group_pk, user_pk):
    invite_user(group_pk, user_pk)

    return render(request, 'groups/show_members.html')
```

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^not_yet_members_list/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.not_yet_members_list, name='not_yet_members_list'),
```

**template.html**:

```
{% for user in not_yet_members %}
    <!-- ??? -->{{ user }}<a href="{% url 'groups:invite_user_view' pk=group.id %}">Invite</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: well you can use session to store them and access in the next view. once the users have been invited clear the session

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the view from where you need to pass the group and user

```
request.session['group_pk'] = group_pk
request.session['user_pk']= user_pk
```

in the view where you need to access the data

```
group_pk =  request.session['group_pk']
user_pk = request.session['user_pk']
```

then

```
invite_user(group_pk, user_pk)
```

after successful sending invitation

```
del request.session['group_pk']
del request.session['user_pk']
request.session.modified = True
```